# How to use reference as file in yaml for separation of configuration?

Tags: yaml, openapi, swagger-codegen, rest, swagger-editor

Can anybody tell me like how i can use schemas from different file into the component by pointing them using like $ref. Need to make seperation for schemas into other files kind of thing.

Comment: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/using-ref/

Comment: Thanks Helen. But, i need to update & make diff files for diff yaml. I tried with ref only and it worked for me. Identation problem was there. I just copied and pasted code into swagger editor tool. And it worked me fine.